# Monitor CPU usage on different machine

Tags: python, virtual-machine, cpu-usage, raspberry-pi2

As my title goes, I tried to look for something can help me to **write the script to get CPU usage from another machine** which will be running *Virtual Machine(VM)*, yes I want to get the CPU usage of the VM which runs ubuntu and runs as *FTP server*. The thing is, I'm still trying to write the script **in Python** which will be **run on Raspberry Pi 2**.

I found a few solution that needs me to use bash scripting, but I need to compile with my script of sending ICMP request to the other machine. The thing is I need to write the script *instead of using another software*. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your current code, have you even tried to solve the problem, have you searched for Python libs to preform this kind of task. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyping/

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try it with VNC but that won't give you a script that will just give you a window into the other machine.